# Enviar texto junto com arquivo FormData Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Estou fazendo um teste com o script abaixo, para upload de arquivo:

```
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("file1").files[0];
    // alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file1", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
```

O que ocorre é que além do arquivo em si, preciso enviar mais 3 campos texto. Tentei com um campo da seguinte forma:

```
var teste = $('input:text[name=teste]').val();
formdata.append("teste", teste);
```

Mas ocorre o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer para mandar essas variáveis? E no `arquivo file_upload_parser.php` como posso receber essas variáveis?

Comment: Diego ai parece que o erro é `$` que não está definido? você usa algum plugin ou extensão que precisa do `jQuery` tipo: `_("file").files[0]` ?

Comment: Não estou usando plugins...

Comment: `_("file1").files[0];` e esse código vem da onde?

Comment: `var teste = $('input:text[name=teste]').val();` olha aonde está o problema isso é jQuery e você disse que não está usando `plugin` ou `framework js` possa ser ai o problema. Então utilize `document.getElementById` e pegue o valor!

Comment: É do formulario o _files, que está funcionando. Vou testar com o getElement

Comment: Deu certo com o getElement. Mas como recebo ela na outra página?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49224/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-diego).